# How do I deal with null and duplicate values in a Java 8 Comparator?

Tags: java, java-8, comparator

I have a `Photo` object:

```
public class Photo {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private LocalDateTime created;
    private Integer poNumber;
}
```

poNumber can be null for some photos or all photos in a set. I want to sort a set of photos according to poNumber, so that the lowest poNumber appears first in the sorted set. poNumber may also be duplicated in the set. If poNumber is duplicated then sort according to created (earliest created photo appears first). If poNumber is null then sort according to created.

I tried the below code:

```
Set<Photo> orderedPhotos = new TreeSet<>(
    Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.comparing(Photo::getPoNumber))
              .thenComparing(Photo::getCreated));

for (Photo photo : unOrderedPhotos) {
    orderedPhotos.add(photo);
}
```

But it throws a `NullPointerException` whenever poNumber is null. If poNumber is not null then it works fine. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Where should elements with `poNumber = null` go? After or before the elements with a non-null value in that field?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a two-argument [Comparator.comparing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-java.util.Comparator-) overload, for example:

```
import static java.util.Comparator.*; // for the sake of brevity

Set<Photo> orderedPhotos = new TreeSet<>(
    Comparator.comparing(Photo::getPoNumber, nullsFirst(naturalOrder()))
              .thenComparing(Photo::getCreated));
```

Answer (score 10):

We need a solution which turns the `Function<>` to a Comparator, but in a way which adds the said `null` checking to the chain.

And that's where [Oleksandr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53337653/296974) enters the scene: it creates a `Comparator` which maps the compared `Photo` to comparing of `Integer`s, and then adds a Comparator which naturally orders these `Integer`s with the `null`s first:

```
Comparator.comparing(Photo::getPoNumber, Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.naturalOrder()))
```

And this comparator is then chained (for the case of equality) with another comparator which considers the creation date.

Answer (score 3):

The way you have written it, the Photo key could be `null` but nothing else.

```
Comparator.nullsFirst( // Photo could be null.
    Comparator.comparing(Comparator.nullsFirst(Photo::getPoNumber)) // poNumber could be null.
              .thenComparing(Comparator.nullsFirst(Photo::getCreated))) // created could be null
```

If any of these can't be `null` you can remove the `Comparator.nullsFirst`

Comment: "But it throws NullPointerException whenever poNumber is null. If poNumber is not null then works fine." There is no mention of `created` being able to be null.

Answer (score 1):

This will put null values at the beginning

```
Integer getPoNumber() { return poNumber == null ? Integer.MIN_VALUE : poNumber };
```

This will put null values at the end

```
Integer getPoNumber() { return poNumber == null ? Integer.MAX_VALUE: poNumber };
```

Otherwise, implement your own comparator to handle the null values

Comment: I dislike `Integer` so would return `int` in this case. ;)

Comment: Its what he's using, but yeah... @ace , Integer.intValue();